# Background and Foreground images in android

Tags: android, image

I'm new to android development. I'm trying to achieve an effect as in steam draw. I have a background image and a foreground image. When I move the finger over the foreground image the corresponding pixels of the foreground image are erased and the background does get visible. Can someone point me in the right direction on how to implement this? Some guide lines?

Thanks in advance.

Pavan